# Vagrant attempted to execute the capability 'mount_virtualbox_shared_folder' error

Tags: vagrant

I'm trying to setup an El Capitan Virtual Machine using Vagrant, and I just keep running into this type of error

"Vagrant attempted to execute the capability 'mount_virtualbox_shared_folder'
on the detect guest OS 'darwin', but the guest doesn't
support that capability. This capability is required for your
configuration of Vagrant. Please either reconfigure Vagrant to
avoid this capability or fix the issue by creating the capability."

I really have no idea what kind of error this is and how to fix it.

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From an [example of vagrant mac os box](https://github.com/AndrewDryga/vagrant-box-osx)

> VirtualBox doesn't have Guest additions for Mac OS X, so you can't
>   have shared folders. Instead you can use normal network shared folders
>   (docs):
>
> ```
> # Use NFS for the shared folder
> config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant",
>     id: "core",
>     :nfs => true,
>     :mount_options => ['nolock,vers=3,udp,noatime']
> ```

Just use the [nfs](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/synced-folders/nfs.html) type as suggested as its supported natively on mac

Comment: Hey - just managed to try this out and it worked!  Thank you so much!  Was smashing my head against a wall there for a couple days.

Comment: What's your host os (and version) and the box you use ? @TimLieberman

Comment: vagrant Installed Version: 1.8.5
Latest Version: 1.8.5 @FrédéricHenri   running on a mac -  still trying to figure this out have multiple people trying to poke at it with no success.

Answer (score 0):

in response to my comment on the accepted answer.  I had to uninstall virtualbox and reinstall it using brew.  Then reinstall vagrant with brew.   not sure using brew had anything to do with it but the virtualbox installer wasn't working either.  It works now.

Comment: weird, I stop using brew cask to install and manage my software as I had issues (brew itself works good, but soft installed with cask has issues and update never worked) - btw vagrant is now on 1.8.6

Comment: yeah it installed latest through brew.  I know packages that aren't managed correctly can have issues when it comes to brew but luckily this all worked just fine